# Connect to MSSQL Server with Python using SQLAlChemy

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy

I have installed SQLAlchemy  2.0.16 on my machine. I am trying to connect to sql server database using below code:

```
from sqlalchemy import text , create_engine
Server = ''
Database = ''
Driver = ''
Database_Con = f'mssql://@{Server}/{Database}?driver={Driver}'
#Create the engine to connect to the database
engine=create_engine(Database_Con)
con = engine.connect()
```

Throws ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyodbc'

If I do a pip install pyodc it works. But my team doesnt want me to install pyodc and want to try to connect to SQLengine. Please let me know any alternatives. Thank You

Comment: *"But my team doesnt want me to install pyodc"* Why not..?

Comment: `doesnt want me to install pyodbc` what do you think SQLAlchemy uses? SQLEngine isn't a data driver. It *uses* the data driver to connect. You still need to install PyODBC and the SQL Server ODBC driver. That's the one supported by Microsoft

Comment: The SQL Server docs [show how to connect in Python](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/python/python-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16). The docs clearly say `Microsoft places its testing efforts and its confidence in pyodbc driver.`

Comment: Will they let you use [pymssql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/python/pymssql/python-sql-driver-pymssql?view=sql-server-ver16), or is that also off limits for undisclosed reasons?

Comment: *I* wouldn't want to use pymssql for any reason, because it relies on FreeTDS which **doesn't support parameters**. Because [they don't think they're a common feature](https://www.freetds.org/faq.html#What.features.are.missing): `Very few programs actually need the missing functionality` Really??????

Comment: @Thom A, From the discussion we had they feel since we already have a sql server ODBC driver why do we need pyodc is the question

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos, Thank you for the resource.  Do you mind me explaining me the exact usage of sqlalchemy and pyodbc please?

Comment: SQLAlchemy is an ORM that generates SQL and maps the results to objects. It doesn't connect to databases itself, it uses Python's DB-API. That in turn used database drivers. ODBC is a standard supported by *all* databases, on all OSs and languages. It does require installing an ODBC driver on the machine but that is usable by all applications, not only those written in a specific language. PyODBC is a Python DB-API implementation over ODBC, which means it too can talk to any database that has an ODBC driver

Comment: I guess your team doesn't install anything except a c compiler, since why do you need finished applications when you can code them from scratch

Comment: you should avoid sqlalchemy as well, because one can write raw cursor code too